# how to get around "This probably means that TCL was not installed properly"?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I am stuck on how to resolve this TCL error

```
 File "draw_box.py", line 53, in <module>
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
  File "/cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1198, in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
  File "/cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 548, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/GPU/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1044, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/cm/shared/apps/anaconda3/4.4.0/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2017, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 /cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/GPU/lib/tcl8.5 /cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/lib/tcl8.5 /cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/GPU/library /cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/library /cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/python3/tcl8.5.18/library /cm/shared/apps/tensorflow/1.4/tcl8.5.18/library
```

Do i need to set an TCL and TK environment? or is this just the path of the TCL8.5 being not in the right location? I am using python3 on a linux terminal (redhat) Any advice to fix this problem would be great!

Comment: Have you thrown the error message at a websearch and read some of the results?

Comment: Anaconda is notorious for its many errors due to how customized each library is. If you could provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we could trouble sheet however seeing that this problem is an anaconda issue I think you would be better off asking on their forums.